# Should a question be closed as off-topic even though a tag exists?

Tags: discussion, tags, vote-to-close, scope

My question refers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687527/problems-submitting-an-app-to-itunes-connect?noredirect=1#comment40147293_25687527).  I have voted to close as I feel that questions about Apple's app submission processes are off-topic as they are not questions about programming.

This is not the first time this has happened where I have voted to close questions and others disagree. It's unclear to me what is on-topic sometimes and perhaps using the tag system is the best way to know.

So am I wrong to vote to close such questions or should the `itunesconnect` tag be removed?

**EDIT** I have [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270754/burninate-itunesconnect) the [itunesconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect) tag be removed.

Comment: It's an important programmer's tool, and tool questions are allowed.

Comment: related: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/839601)

Comment: In general, existence of prior questions or a tag doesn't automatically make a question on-topic. There are many questions and tags that are historical in nature, before other (more appropriate now) SE sites existed. (There are probably thousands of OS and hardware related questions at SO that were on-topic when asked, but would belong on [su] or [ubuntu.se] or [apple.se] if asked now.) Whether a question is on-topic or not depend on the guidelines that are in place *at the time the question is asked*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the general case, yes. The existence of a tag doesn't mean that any question you could possibly apply that tag to is a good question for Stack Overflow. If the question is off topic, close it as off-topic. If the tag is one that couldn't possibly be applied to an on-topic question, come to Meta and suggest burnination, possibly with massive close and delete campaign against existing bad questions.

As for this specific tag, it's arguably a tool primarily used by programmers, but Stack Overflow shouldn't be a substitute for Apple customer support. If the question is clearly not related to programming, I'd probably vote to close many of them.

Comment: OK thanks for the input and I will initiate a burnination for tag `itunesconnect`.

Comment: Related: [All that a blatantly off-topic tag is gonna do is encourage blatantly off-topic questions, so removing it is good for everyone.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268202/792066)

Answer (score 10):

Please note that it is possible for all of these to be true:

- The tag is applied to on-topic questions and should continue to exist.
- A question is obviously related to that tag.
- The question is completely off-topic.

For example, [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) should be used for programming questions about Microsoft Excel, but 99% of possible questions about Excel would be off-topic here because they don't involve programming.