# Burninate [itunesconnect]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Following on from this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270744/should-a-question-be-closed-as-off-topic-even-though-a-tag-exists?noredirect=1#comment90742_270744) I would like to suggest [itunesconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect) is removed from Stack Overflow as it is not directly related to programming, but is used by iPhone/OSX app developers to manage their app submissions with Apple.

Apple are best suited to support issues with iTunes Connect, not Stack Overflow, and any answers Stack Overflow users can provide are not programming related, but rather how to use a website.

Comment: It would probably be better to work on closing the questions in that tag that are off-topic first. There are over 1600 questions right now, and only 200 are closed. There have been 600 that were deleted, which doesn't look good, but it still doesn't show that a majority are off-topic.

Comment: Let's add [tag:itunes-store] to the clean-up scope. I've seen a bunch of off-topic questions there as well.