# Need clear direction on App Store questions

Tags: support, vote-to-close, scope

I'm trying to find a definitive answer to the on-topic-ness (or off-topic-ness) of App Store questions. App Store questions would include Apple's App Store, Google's Play, Microsoft's Windows' Store, Amazon's Appstore, etc.

I've found a few related questions, but I feel like they are missing clear direction for policy decisions. For example:

- [Should a question be closed as off-topic even though a tag exists?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270744/should-a-question-be-closed-as-off-topic-even-though-a-tag-exists)
- [Burninate [itunesconnect]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270754/burninate-itunesconnect) (unanswered)

Do App Store questions fall under the ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clause, and therefore are on-topic?

Or do App Store questions fail to satisfy the ["a specific programming problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clause, and therefore are off-topic?

How should App Store questions be handled?

---

Related: here's the question that triggered the inquiry: [How to download apk to computer from Amazon app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877411/how-to-download-apk-to-computer-from-amazon-app-store?noredirect=1#comment40757106_25877411).

The question was updated after being closed. Please check the revision history if needed.

Comment: Here's what would have been the [meta-tag:faq] entry on the subject, but since the meta split it's pretty much pointless... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175701/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic-for-stack-over

Comment: Thanks @Will. I believe I saw that in the past, but I could not locate it. Its closed on Meta.SE as off-topic. I flagged it and asked the mods to migrate it to Meta.SO.

Comment: I know a question is off topic only after reading it.  Nothing based on something as crude as an "app store" selector.  That question is quite hopeless, massive XY.  Imagine the horror of it turning into the reference question for a segfault problem :)  Close it, quickly, before it escapes.

Comment: Why don't we just migrate Will's question here? It was originally asked on Meta.SO anyways.

Comment: I flagged it as well.  We'll see if somebody takes action.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Josh. I did not see the migration. I'm moving to close this question.