# Why is iTunesConnect off topic?

Tags: discussion

Questions relating to iTunesConnect are off topic, and I tend agree. They're not programming questions.

However, the [What Topics Can I Ask About Here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) document seems to disagree. In particular, I think that questions about iTunesConnect fit quite nicely into two of the four points:

- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

It's certainly a tool used commonly by programmers and I can't think how a software distribution tool isn't unique to software development.

So why did the community decide that these questions are off topic? Does the [What Topics Can I Ask About Here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page need updating?

Comment: Can you point to a specific example question?

Comment: @Pekka웃, it was a [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270754/burninate-itunesconnect) that spawned this question. I haven't seen one recently

Comment: I'd lump in questions about Apple's review policies on app submission with this (equally off topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd first and foremost classify iTunesConnect as a *cloud service* rather than a "tool". Vague distinction, I know. The issue with *services* such as this are as follows though:

1. It's not a very complex service which would spawn a lot of in-detail questions. Most issues are probably about usage of the service, for which there should be a manual. For the most part there either is a button for what you want to do or there isn't.
2. Most problems which you encounter are probably simply bugs or outages, which only Apple can fix or properly respond to.
3. It's a moving target. Nobody controls iTunesConnect but Apple. They may change and update the service at any time. There are no version numbers and there's no way to get to older versions of the service. Once Apple changes something, any or all previously posted topics in the tag may get invalidated. Questions about Visual GNU++ '11 version 5.4.42.1 will always stay as useful as they were the day they were posted; questions about iTunesConnect probably won't.

All this together means that the tag would mostly serve as a temporary forum for talking about the service and sharing tips and tricks. And that's not what SO is for. This goes for any and all things which are mostly 3rd-party hosted cloud services.

Comment: related: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/839601)

Comment: Disagree on all points: 1. maybe they *shouldn't* be, but app stores are in fact quite complex now, even filtering to just the developer side bits - e.g. automated store metadata updates. 2. finding out if something is a bug and what the workaround is if so is something SO is very useful for. I can't comment on "most", but I've personally hit a lot of not-bug questions dealing with app stores. 3. sort of right, though I would argue that questions that are about a single version of a software tool released X years ago are not that much more useful.