# Are questions about the Google Analytics reporting interface on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I work pretty much exclusively on the Google Analytics tag. I'm not much of a stickler for the rules, but when people ask about the reporting interface I usually leave a comment that this is off-topic (since questions about the interface are not about programming,  software algorithms, tools specifically used by programmers, or practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development).

However, I *am* bothered when someone claims that ["I am not making sense" when pointing out OT questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298382/frequency-and-recency-how-to-interpret-the-results?noredirect=1#comment56340972_34298382) as it occasionally happens.

So I'd like to have an authoritative answer to the question in the title, i.e. "are questions about the Google Analytics reporting interface on topic" (this is a near-duplicate to a lot of questions here, but unless it is explicitly spelled out I will have the same discussion over and over).

Comment: Was their argument _seriously_ that since there's a tag it's on-topic? I thought you were talking to a low-rep user there and the confusion would be understandable as a new user- 22k rep and using an excuse like that? Does this guy understand the point of the site? (And no, the interface is _not_ on topic unless you're doing something programtically with it. I doubt there's a whole lot anyone can do with Google's user interface, but it could happen.)

Comment: If they don't actually come here, I would also point them to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and see if they can point out how that question fits the on-topic guidelines.

Comment: @Kendra, I linked to the help center. That did not help. I really don't want to make to much of an issue of that, it would simply help if I could point to a post where this is discussed and settled.

Comment: It'll take a bit for enough consensus to be made here to prove to the user that this is off-topic. (I had missed that you linked to that, sorry!) I'm trying to see if I can find a question about having a tag making everything of a given topic on-topic- I feel like that's come up before, and that _would_ help prove to this user that the guideline isn't "if there's a tag, everything goes!"

Comment: @Kendra, it adds to the problem that Google Analytics has branched out in a way that makes the plain "google-analytics"-tag too broad to be useful ( I probably would make another meta post from that if I would see any way to resolve or improve this).

Comment: Here we go! Found a post that should help: [Should a question be closed as off-topic even though a tag exists?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270744/should-a-question-be-closed-as-off-topic-even-though-a-tag-exists) I would link [the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270745/2607247) directly to the OP on main and point out that the existence of a tag does not make an off-topic question automatically on-topic.

Comment: I don't really know anything about Google Analytics, but it sounds like a tool aimed at web developers.  Unless these are general reports that even management can use?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, GA is a tool for marketers (it was specifically introduced to support the Google Adwords program) and data analysts. Web developers usually do the implementation (questions about which are IMO on topic, and I have answered some 630 of them in the last three years).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Okay, then I agree questions about interpreting the reports are off-topic.

Comment: AFAIK, there's [webapps.se]. That might deal with the web interface for Google Analytics. (let me check it once again). Edit: there is. Also, another site is [webmasters.se]

Comment: Which network site would this be most on-topic at? I asked it here seeing other similar GA questions and got chewed out. :S

Comment: @MelaniePalen maybe webmasters.se is an option. First visit their help https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help;  meta https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&pagesize=15&q=analytics&searchOn=3 and see if the tag has similar questions: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics before you ask a new question there.  Also note that we have [site-recommendations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info) on Meta.se; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40502 which can help finding the right site, if any.

Answer (score 5):

No, Google Analytics usage questions like this are off-topic. This is not a tool used for programming nor is programming involved in the usage of Google Analytics reports/dashboards. The only Google Analytics questions that are on-topic are those involving how to implement Google Analytics on a webpage since those questions involve writing code in web languages like HTML and JavaScript.

You can ask general usage Google Analytics questions on the following network sites:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

In order of preference.